# resizing a form according to the size of the datagridview that it contains

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

my datagridview is connected to a data source:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = mydatatable;
```

I want to present this data to the user. If it has more than X lines then it will have a vertical scrollbar.

Placing it in a form does not look good, because the size of the form can be bigger than  the size of the datatable. I tried to manually resize the form according to the size of the datagridview like this:

```
this.Size = dataGridView1.Size;
```

but it does not work (if the datagridview is smaller, it does not make the form smaller. If it is bigger than it covers some of it). Perhaps there is a way to present the table without going through a form ? or is there a way to resize it correctly ?

I have tried the following (in response to an answer):

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = competingCourses; 
this.dataGridView1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = dataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

I also have:

```
this.AutoSize=true; 
this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

it still does not change the size of the containing form.

Comment: Have you tried `dataGridView1.Height`?

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing a new `Size` object from the Height and Width of the DataGridView, then assign it to the forms Size:

```
Size newSize = new Size(dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height);
this.Size = newSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the form based on its content automatically by setting `Autosize=True` and `AutoSizeMode=GrowAndShrink` on the form.

Comment: this.dataGridView1.DataSource = competingCourses;

this.dataGridView1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;            

this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = dataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;


after adding your suggestion above I also have: 

this.AutoSize=true;
this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

it still does not change the size of the containing form.

Comment: @user1743977 you have the right to edit your question, and this is encouraged. Code like you have given in your comment should be added to your question. I've done that for you here.